# Play .mov or .avi in BGE

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I am trying to make an explosion in the game engine, using GLSL shading.
The Alpha works so all you can see is the fire, but blender is treating it as an image texture and not playing the video.

Are there any easy ways to make the game engine play animated textures? I do **not** mean by using this method:

[image]

Comment: I vaguely recall someone made a commit to BGE regarding playing videos sometime about a month or two ago.  If you feel like doing some digging.  http://www.miikahweb.com/en/blender/git-logs/page/0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play videos (and images and render from other cameras) with the VideoTexture module.

You can test that with [Dynamic Texture 1.0 - easy to use VideoTexture](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?341884).

Edit: You can find the official documentation of the VideoTexture module (incl. example) in the [BGE API](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bge.texture.html).

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please add more info here, explain the process of using your videoTexture module, how it works etc. 
Just posting a blend file would not be a very good answer, but just posting a link to a place to download a blend file, can hardily be considered an answer.